# Get email of user that is logged in in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a question about wordpress. I need a function that can return me the email of the user that is logged in. I'm interested in Authors. Can anybody help me? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, please always remember to Google before asking. Searching `Get email of user that is logged in in wordpress` gets me the right answer on the 1st position

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In wordpress, you can use below function:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo $current_user->user_email;
```

For latest version WordPress 4.5 and greater

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
echo $current_user->user_email;
```

Comment: Yes, it is deprecated now, You need to use wp_get_current_user.Updated answer

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `wp_get_current_user()` function as outlined in the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user).

An example of using this would be something like the following.

```php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
return $current_user->user_email;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();

  echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
  echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
  echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
  echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
  echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
  echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
```

?>

you will get output like

```
Username: Zedd
User email: my@email.com
User first name: John
User last name: Doe
User display name: John Doe
User ID: 1
```

Comment: answer is now obsolete.